# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'psycopg2' when redshift connection is added to the Gluejob

Tags: amazon-redshift, psycopg2, aws-glue, python-module

I'm using glue to load data from redshift, glubjob is failing with psycopg2 import error. 1) I tried
--additional-python-modules method to import psycopg2-binary, glue is importing the module like this, Collecting psycopg2-binary  Downloading psycopg2_binary-2.9.3-cp37-cp37m-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (3.0 MB)Installing collected packages: psycopg2-binarySuccessfully installed psycopg2-binary-2.9.3.
But the job is failed with below error,
redshift.amazonaws.com", port 5439 failed: Connection timed out
Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?

2. I tried by attaching redshift connection to the glue job, this time it is failed with ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'psycopg2' error and below is the reason for that,Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/psycopg2-binary/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/psycopg2-binary/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: UNKNOWN_PROTOCOL] unknown protocol (_ssl.c:1091)'))) - skippingCould not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: UNKNOWN_PROTOCOL] unknown protocol (_ssl.c:1091)'))) - skipping

I have tried other options like zipping the psycopg2-binary module, uploading it to s3 and used the path in python library path in glue but still getting module not found error.
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue for a different set of libraries. Even i installed the libraries it was throwing the error. so I found out about this code snip and added in my code and it worked for me.
You can add at the start of your script and see if this works for you.

```
# Load all the custom modules which are required by the glue script.
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '/glue/lib/installation')
keys = [k for k in sys.modules.keys() if 'boto' in k]
for k in keys:
    if 'boto' in k:
        del sys.modules[k]
```

Here is the link to the guide for Installing Additional Python Modules in glue -
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-programming-python-libraries.html

Comment: Thank you, I have tried this approach for pyshell job, It is working fine but when I'm trying with pyspark job It is failing with "module not found error". May I know how you uploaded the python modules to s3 bucket, did you use .whl or .zip files?

Comment: i uploaded whl files on s3